# n+1 issue in ActiveAdmin model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, eager-loading

I have a model with a has_many association causing the index page of of parent model to hang. The associated table has 517k records. I have attempted eager loading in the model and the ActiveAdmin model. The bullet gem keeps telling my I have unused eager loading when I attempt below. So I am very confused now.

design.rb

```
has_many :users_designs
```

designs_controller

```
@designs = Design.where("item_id = ?", @item.id).order(:item_id, :id).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 200).includes(:users_designs, :company)
```

ActiveAdmin Model

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    ItemsDesign.includes(:users_designs)
  end
end
```

Comment: If `item_id` is a foreign key in `designs` table then you don't need `includes(:users_designs, :company)`.

Comment: OK, that's what I originally thought. But the performance issues lead me down the eager loading path, Any idea how I can address the this hanging issue?

Comment: I'm assuming it's the `paginate` that's causing the issue.  Have you tried without it?  Also, eager loading is useful only when you have reference to attributes from multiple "associated" models.